# Using Google Earth Engine to clip images according to region polygon shape when exporting to Drive?

Tags: export, clip, google-earth-engine

Normally, I do export images which are rectangles whatever the shape of the region is, then I clip them on a GIS software.

Is there a way to do it directly in GEE?

This is the code I use for exporting

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mejorImagen,
  description: 'Landsat8_Ab_2013',
  scale: 30,
  region: Abast
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can clip them in GEE the same way as you would with a GIS, i.e. masking everything outside your clip geometry.

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mejorImagen.clip(your_clip_geometry),
  description: 'Landsat8_Ab_2013',
  scale: 30,
  region: Abast
  });
```

Comment: I did this and I have the clip area but with black background filling to make up a rectangle

Comment: That is to be expected. The display of "No Data" areas as black or transparent is a convention by the software you use to display it. There are no empty pixels in the file itself.

Comment: But In Arcgis when I clip a raster I do get the actual clip area, with no black filling or something.

Comment: It will still be a rectangle full of pixel values, only that ArcGIS does not display the pixels with the value that is marked in the metadata as "No Data".